# In Flutter, how would I place a caption like a overlay on a ClipArt?

Tags: flutter, stack, overlay, opacity

Please, take a look at the attached screenshots.
The left image is what I currently have. A ClipRect widget displaying a local image:

```
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  width: 250,
  height: 350,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/$image.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
);
```

It's depicting on the right (red arrow) what I have in mind.
I suspect it would involve a Stack, a Positioned, and maybe an Opacity, but I don't know where to begin.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  width: 250,
  height: 350,
  child: Stack(children:[
  ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/$image.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
              child: Text('blablabla'),
            ),
          ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` will be what are you looking for , wrap your `ClipArt` with `Stack` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim,

Your response led me to a solution. For a Positioned widget to work, however, the enclosing Stack must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets and not RenderObjectWidgets like the ClipRRect I was originally using. I had to enclose the image in a StatelessWidget I called, StackImage.

```
class PicTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const PicTab({Key key, @required this.name, @required this.state})
      : super(key: key);
  final String name;
  final SubmodulesState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    String image;

    if (name == null || name.isEmpty) {
      image = 'river_bend';
    } else {
      image = name.trim();
    }
    final stackImage = StackImage(name: 'assets/images/$image.jpg');
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 3),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          stackImage,
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: stackImage.width,
              height: stackImage.height * 0.3,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Text(''),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StackImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackImage({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
    this.width = 250,
    this.height = 250,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String name;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  @override
  Container build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          child: Image.asset(
            name,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: good to hear that you got your own solution working!